# How to make search bar background transparent with a colored gradient over it

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a search bar with a transparent background so that the image of the parent still shows, but I want to add a different color layer over that and have the image still show dimly in the background.

Comment: Hey you haven't accepted my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the alpha value for the background color like this

```js
#searchbar{
    /*some other code like positioning*/
    background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
}
```

I have here the example of dim red color. You can give any color you want in RGB value in the first 3 arguments and the 4th argument is the alpha value, i.e., the transparency value.

Greater is the value, opaque will be the color, smaller the value, transparent will be the background. Max value will be 1(totally opaque) and min value is 0(totally transparent).